# Columns/ReportBody based on Parameter Selection in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2016

SSRS Report with one Parameter-selection as BusinessUnit with 3 Options( CustomerService, Sales, Inventory).
As per requirement, with the option Selected, User should be able to View Columns/Fields and Rows respective to choosen BusinessUnit-Parameter value.

Example: If user Selects BusinessUnit (Parameter) = CustomerService.
Report should display:  | Col_CS1 | Col_CS2 | Col_CS3 | Col_CS4 |

When BusinessUnit (Parameter) = Sales.
Report fields: |Col_S1 | Col_S2 | Col_S3 | Col_S4 | Col_S5 |Col_S6|

When BusinessUnit (Parameter) = Inventory
Report Fields: |Col_inv1| Col_Inv2 | Col_Inv3 |

Also Report will be a Drill Through SSRS Report.

Really appreciate any leads/help in achieving the about scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use three tablixes in your report with the related / fields datasets.

Use visibility expressions to show only one tablix based on the parameter choice.

eg. for service tablix use the following visibility(hidden) expression `=(Parameters!BusinessUnit.Value <> "CustomerService")`

Also because datasets will execute even if tablix is hidden, on each dataset query add an expression that returns rows only if the proper parameter choice is made.

eg.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE .....
    AND @BusinessUnit = 'CustomerService'
```